# Understanding socket basics

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I've been reading up on basic network programming, but am having a difficult time finding a straight-forward explanation for what exactly and socket is, and how it relates to either the OSI or TCP/IP stack.

1. Can someone explain to me what a socket is? Is it a programmer- or API-defined data structure, or is it a hardware device on a network card?
2. What layers of the mentioned network models deal with "raw" sockets? Transport layer? Network layer?
3. In terms of the data they pass between them, are socket text-based or binary?
4. Is there an **alternative** to sockets-based network programming? Or do all networked applications use some form of socket?

If I can get this much I should have a pretty clear understanding of everything else I'm reading. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answers:

1. Socket is an abstraction of an IP connection endpoint - so if you think of it as an API structure, you are not very far off. Please do read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket
2. [Internet layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Layer) i.e. IP Protocol. In practice you usually use explicitly sockets that bind to a certain transport layer parameters (datagram/UDP or stream/TCP)
3. Sockets send data, in network byte order - whether it is text or binary, depends on the upper layer protocol.
4. Theoretically, probably yes - but in practice all IP traffic is done using 'sockets'

Comment: Thanks Kimvais! So, is it safe to say that a someone implementing a socket structure must allow it conform to IP protocol?

Comment: ...Also, if sockets are IP-level constructs, then what is the distinction between a socket implementing IPv4 or IPSec?

Comment: Sockets do not (generally) implement IPSec - you (usually) just use the 'ordinary' TCP or UDP socket to create the traffic and the lower levels of the network stack (possibly on a different network node) handle the ESP transform for IPSec. From an application programmer point of view, there should be no difference between IPv4 and IPv6 sockets excect the addresses you need to use when opening the socket.

Comment: (3) is not correct. Sockets send *data* in whatever order you send it, not in network byte order. That's only for IP, UDP, and TCP headers.

Answer (score 4):

Socket is a software mechanism provided by the operating system. Like its name implies, you can think of it like an "electrical outlet" or some electrical connector, even though socket is not a physical device, but a software mechanism. In real world when you have two electrical connectors, you can connect them with a wire. In the same way in network programming you can create one socket on one computer and another socket on another computer and then connect those sockets. And when you write data to one of them, you receive it on the other one. There are also a few different kinds of sockets. For example if you are programming a server software, you want to have a listening socket which never sends or receives actual data but only listens for and accepts incoming connections and creates a new socket for each new connection.

Comment: Who takes care of sending data from one end to the other?

Answer (score 3):

A socket, in C parlance, is a data structure in kernel space, corresponding to one end-point of a UDP or TCP session (I am using session *very* loosely when talking about UDP). It's normally associated with one single port number on the local side and seldom more than one "well-known" number on either side of the session.

A "raw socket" is an end-point on, more or less, the physical transport. They're seldom used in applications programming, but sometimes used for various diagnostic things (traceroute, ping, possibly others) and may required elevated privileges to open.

Sockets are, in their nature, a binary octet-transport. It is not uncommon to treat sockets (TCP sockets, at least) as being text-based streams.

I have not yet seen a programming model that doesn't involve something like sockets, if you dig deep enough, but there have certainly been other models of doing networking. The "/net/" pseudo-filesystem, where opening "/net/127.0.0.0.1/tcp/80" (or "tcp/www") would give you a file handle where writes end up on a web server on localhost is but one.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `your PC at home`, and you have `two browser` windows open.

One looking at the `facebook website`, and the other at the `Yahoo website`.

The connection to facebook would be:

`Your PC – IP1+port 30200 ——– facebook IP2 +port 80 (standard port)`

The `combination IP1+30200 = the socket on the client computer` and `IP2 + port 80 = destination socket on the facebook server`.

The connection to Yahoo would be:

`your PC – IP1+port 60401 ——–Yahoo IP3 +port 80 (standard port)`

`The combination IP1+60401 = the socket on the client computer` and`IP3 + port 80 = destination socket on the Yahoo server`.